# Upgrade from IIS 7.0 to IIS 7.5 in Windows 7

Tags: windows, iis-7, iis-7.5

I have currently got IIS 7.0 running on my Windows 7 Professional 64 bit Service Pack 1 machine. I want to upgrade to IIS 7.5 but I can't see how to do this. Do I need to upgrade to another version of Windows 7? Thanks. Below is the version of IIS I'm running.

[image: This is the version of IIS I'm running]

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 should come with IIS 7.5 (7.0 shipped with Vista/2K8).

To install 7.5 paste *Turn Windows features on or off* into the search box and select *Internet Information Services*.

Comment: That's what I did when I originally installed it - but it put in version 7 (see my edit)

Comment: Odd My Win7 x64 has 7.5.7600